# Console mono executables do not exit when completed

Tags: macos, mono, ikvm

I have a .NET project that I've been compiling with Visual Studio and running successfully on Windows for years.  I'd like to move to use Mac OS X to run this particular program, and so have been working with mono for just a little while do make that possible.  The results have been excellent, with the program performing as expected under mono (2.10.9, BTW).

The only hitch is that the program does not exit after it is done.  It is a single-threaded process, but when its work is completed (which it reports at the end of the `Main(string[])` method), the process does not exit; `^C` is required to return to the shell prompt.  Adding an explicit `System.Environment.Exit(exitCode);` call at the end has no effect.

I found only one other tale of this sort of problem from some years ago, [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-devel-list@lists.ximian.com/msg05462.html), though that ML thread provided no potential solution.

Comment: Try running with gdb (`gdb --args mono yourapp.exe`, then `run`), and when the app should have exited, you press Ctrl-C (which will give you a (gdb) prompt). Then you get a stack trace for all threads (thread apply all backtrace), which should tell you if mono deadlocked upon shutdown (which is what I believe happens). With that information it might be possible to give more clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolf (in his comment on the question) was right, the vm was deadlocking upon shutdown.

I'm using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) in this application, and there are certain circumstances where it needs to start a thread at vm shutdown to clean up its JVM<->CLR interop machinery; this apparently does not sit well with mono (but always works in .NET).

This was discovered on [a thread on the IKVM dev list](https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=B75FBFED-D6C4-4E19-BD7E-B4F331F3C3E9%40snowtide.com&forum_name=ikvm-developers) by IKVM's author, who filed [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5650) with the mono project.

The workaround in my case was to explicitly call `java.lang.System.exit(exitCode)` instead of simply letting the program terminate naturally or using `System.Environment.Exit(exitCode)`.  This allows IKVM to shut down outside of the vm termination lifecycle, thereby avoiding the mono bug.